# Multiple dex files define Lokhttp3/Interceptor

Tags: android

После подключения зависимости

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.6.0'
```

я получила ошибку о превышении количества методов для одного DEX-файла.
После этого добавила в *build.gradle* настройку `multiDexEnabled true`, но всё равно получаю ошибку:

> Error:Error converting bytecode to dex:
>
> Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define
> Lokhttp3/Interceptor;
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.

В чём причина этой ошибки и как её можно исправить?

Comment: Покажите ваш build.gradle проекта

Comment: добавьте вывод команды `gradlew app:dependencies --configuration releaseCompileClasspath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помимо включения `multiDexEnabled` Вам нужно подключить библиотеку для мультидекса:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

Синхронизируйтесь. Затем создать(или следать наследование для сущесвтующего) класс, который наследуется от

```
public class App extends MultiDexApplication
```

И последний шаг - указать этот класс в манифесте в теге `<application>`

```
  <application
    android:name=".app.App"
    ...>
```